# Array from js file won't export to express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a small recipe app to learn express and mongoDB.

I created a form and I am able to get the values back and sent to the DB , but what i would like would be to be able to add ingredients in an array in the form and then export the array alongside the other values.

Here is my server file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/recipes', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('connected to DB')
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log('Something went wrong');
        console.log(e);
    })

const ingredients = require('atittude');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require ('path');
const methodOverride = require ('method-override');
const fs = require('fs');
const multer = require('multer');


const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))



app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'))

const recipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category : {
        type : [String],
        required : true,
        enum : ['comfort', 'healthy', 'favorite', 'quick', 'cheap', 'fancy']
    },
    time : Number,
    ingredient: [String],
    recipeBody : String,
    img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
})

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

app.post('/add', (req,res) => {
    const {name, category, time, ingredient, recipeBody} = req.body
    console.log(`${name},${category},${time},${ingredient},${recipeBody},`)
    const img = req.file
    const recipe = new Recipe({name, category, time, ingredient, recipeBody})
    recipe.save()
.then(data => {
        console.log("It worked.")
        console.log(data);
    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error : ')
            console.log(err)
        })
    res.render('home', {name, category, time, ingredient, recipeBody})
})

app.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    res.render('new')
})





app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

Here is my ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>New Recipe</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add a new recipe</h1>
<form action="/add" method="POST" id="mainform" enctype="x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <label for="name">Name : </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the recipe..." name="name">
    <label for="category">Categories : </label>
    <select id="category" name="category" size="6" multiple>
        <option value="comfort">Comfort</option>
        <option value="healthy">Healthy</option>
        <option value="favorite">Kids' favorites</option>
        <option value="quick">Quick</option>
        <option value="cheap">Cheap</option>
        <option value="fancy">Fancy</option>
    </select>
    <label for="time">Time : </label>
    <input name="time" type="text">
    <label for="ingredient">Add ingredient </label>
    <input name="ingredient" id="ingredient" type="text">

    <button id="addingredient">Add !</button>
    <textarea id="recipe" name="recipeBody" rows="4" cols="50">
  Recipe here...
  </textarea>
    <input type="file" name="img" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<ul id="ingList">

</ul>
<script type="module" src="/js/atittude.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js file to add ingredients to the page

```
const adding = document.querySelector('#addingredient');
let currentIngredient = document.querySelector('#ingredient');
let ingredients = [];
const list = document.querySelector('#ingList');

adding.addEventListener("click", (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault()
    ingredients.push(currentIngredient.value)
    console.log(ingredients);
    const newIngredient = document.createElement('li')
    newIngredient.innerText = ingredients[ingredients.length-1];
    list.append(newIngredient);
    export {ingredients};


})
```

I get an error `atittude.js:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export`

I would like to be able to export my ingredients array to app.js to then send it to mongo.

Or should i do code the option to add ingredients to the list server side on in my ejs file using <%= ?

Sorry if some of the code is bad practice i'm learning.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

that's good that you're learning. If I get your question correctly, you are trying to send the array of ingredients to your server in order to save it in your DB. There are many ways to solve your problem here and they all involve sending a request from your client (the browser with the rendered ejs file) to your server (your nodejs app).

A straightforward way you can do this is to use the `fetch` api (you can check out the Mozilla Docs, they have excellent tutorias) to POST the ingredients like so:

```
fetch('/add', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(ingredientsObj)
  })
.then(function(response) {
  // Do stuff with the response
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
});
```

You might want to consider securing your request with access controls and other parameters, as well as sanitizing your input to make sure it arrives in the right format you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Basically what I would like to do would be for the form to send the value of the array ingredients instead of the value of the field. I get the fields value using req.body , I thought I could just export my array but it's not working. Could I fetch the array on submit ?